# Google Map dragging like in maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-maps

I just want to add the effect of map momentum by the dragging of map as in maps.google.com has.

Currently on my map where I stop dragging the map stops there but in maps.google.com if you drag a mouse the map will not stop there it will continue the movement in the same direction for a second or a few coordinates (I don't know), and I want the same thing on my Google Map. I am using GMap2.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to Google Maps v3. That's your easiest solution, and your users will be better off in the long run.

Comment: hi i have also tried on google map 3 but there is no such options related to what i want, hope you have check out http://maps.google.com here if you click on a map and drag it and leave the mouse it will continue its movement for a while that is what i am looking for but unable to do it please help